# React & Enzyme/Jest: beforeEach() to group variables & use before in each unit test best practice?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am working on my first react unit test and would like to know if there is a best practice for grouping variables used in every unit test? I have a group of unit tests for a form that uses the same variables.  I grouped them in an 'describe(){}' and would like to have the variables at the beginning of each test.  My approach is below, but I am receiving an error that says 'ReferenceError: input is not defined'.

If I do not wrap them in a beforeEach(), then I receive errors for the 'screen.getByText' lines that it was 'Unable to find an element with the text' even though it's wrapped in an await.

The tests run fine if I have the variables repeated in each test, but that would be a lot of duplicated code as I have 6 tests within the describe().

```
import { render, fireEvent, wait, cleanup, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';


describe('testing subscription form validation', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    let handleChange = jest.fn();
    let {getByTestId} = render(<Form handleChange={handleChange}/>);
    let input = getByTestId('test-input');
    let button = screen.getByTestId('test-button');
  });

  it('[some test description]', async () => {
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: '[test value]' } });
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(screen.getByText('[button text]')).toBeInTheDocument();
    await wait(() => expect(input).toHaveAttribute('value', 'test value'));
  });

  it('[another test]', async () => {
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: '' } }); 
    fireEvent.click(button);
    await wait(() => {
        const requiredText = screen.getByText('This field is required');
        expect(requiredText).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

Thank you for taking the time to help!  Any guidance would be great.

Comment: Please note, I was able to use the approach provided by the answer below except I needed to keep `let {getByTestId} = render(<Form handleChange={handleChange}/>);` within the beforeEach() function.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more here. How are you able to access getByTestId inside your it/test blocks? Isnt it undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dclare the variables outside the function and assign to them inside your `beforeEach()`, like so:

```
describe('hdgsbdicg', () => {
    let input;

    bedoreEach(() => {
        input=jest.fn(); //or whatever
    }
});
```

Comment: how will this work if you want to destructure some variables from the render fn? For example:
beforeEach(() => { const { getByText } = render (<SomeComponent />). How can I use getByText inside of my tests?

Comment: simply use a destructured variables reassignment, like so: `( { thing1, thing2 } = myObj );`

Comment: ahh, got it! Never seen that before thanks